# Automated way to parse a string to a target primitive type (in runtime)

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, dynamic

I want to create a method that gets a **number-formatted string**, like "123" and parses it to a primitive number type, like an int. The type is unknown at compile time, so **I cannot make use of Generics**.

My first approach was:

```
public object DynamicParse(string input, Type targetType) 
{
    if (targetType == typeof(int)) 
    {
        return int.Parse(input);
    } 
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The string cannot be converted");
    }
}
```

OK, fair enough, but what if I also want to handle float, double, long, decimal...?

The conditionals will get pretty repetitive like:

```
if (targetType == typeof(x)) 
{
    x.Parse(input);
}
```

5 times!

Is there a better way to automate this avoiding duplication?

Comment: It is not clear exactly _why_ you want to do this. If you can pass the `Type` reference, typically you could just call that type's `Parse()` method directly. In any case, the marked duplicate has a number of answers addressing this sort of thing, including one basically identical to the answer posted below.

Comment: Why? =>I'm using it for a parser that will attempt to convert the input string to a target type. One of the possible conversions is to a number. In that case, it will use the .NET built-in parsers to convert the string.

Comment: The most voted answer in that question is smart and it works, but in my case, the type isn't known at compile time. The proposed solutions make use of Generics for the parsing. Sorry, but I think it's not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) to do parsing for your:

```
static T DynamicParse<T>(string s) {
    return (T) Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T));
}

string s = "123";
int i = DynamicParse<int>(s);
double d = DynamicParse<double>(s);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/qWC3s5)

Comment: Coo! but how to avoid invalid conversion attempts? Is there a way better than a try-catch block? I'll use this in a parser and it will be called multiple times, and lots of the calls will contain strings that are not parsable. I would probably change it to be a bool TryDynamicParse(string, Type, out result).

Comment: @SuperJMN Unfortunately, `ChangeType` does not offer a `TryChangeType` counterpart, so you would need a `try` / `catch` with this approach.